# Is there a Catalyst tutorial that uses HTML::Template instead of TT?

Tags: perl, catalyst, template-toolkit, perl-html-template

I've been looking through a couple of Catalyst tutorials and they all tend to use Template Toolkit instead of HTML::Template.

I've spent a lot of time with HTML::Template and I like it, and while I can see the power of TT, I don't know it, and I feel like I'd be learning two things at once; plus, because it does its processing in-template, I'm not sure where my HTML::Template `$template->param(foo => \$bar);` code would even go!

Anyone know a good tutorial/code sample using HTML::Template?

Answer (score 16):

Granted, the documentation on [Catalyst::View::HTML::Template](http://search.cpan.org/~mramberg/Catalyst-View-HTML-Template-0.02/lib/Catalyst/View/HTML/Template.pm) is a little sparse and it's not a tutorial per se, but it does cover configuring the basic HTML::Template settings (`die_on_bad_params`, etc.) and states that "*Template params are set up from the contents of $c->stash*", which looks to me like it should be enough to get you started.